# Create Button on dynamics CRM with multiple workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

We have a change request form that we want to have multiple verify buttons on it and based on the workflow sends the form to different people.
I don't know how to add one button and run multiple workflows

Comment: If I get you right, you need one workflow, which decides to whom to send the form and one button which fires the workflow

Comment: Thank you for your answer. let me explain a little more.
for example, the NOC manager and Change manager should confirm fields of the form in their queue. both of them should see the approval button but the trickier part is based on the manager role or the field value the action or workflow is doing something different.  but all of them see the button on top of the form

Comment: You can create html control (approval button) web resource, place it on the form. On button click you can access form fields via `parent.Xrm` and do you checkings and after that fire the workflow or the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workflow to Determine Who to Email

Your workflow can access fields from the `Change Request` record, so may be able to determine what actions it should take (e.g. send to person A if status is completed).

### Workflow Button & Button Access

You can create a custom button using Ribbon Workbench that calls this workflow.

You can restrict visibility of the custom button using security roles. You can add a custom display rule to your custom button that uses JavaScript to check the current users security roles. If they have the required security role the button will be visible, otherwise it will be visible.

There are plently of tutorials on how to do this, just make sure to use one that was created in the last couple years.

#### Alternative Solutions

- Ribbon Workbench has a feature called [Smart Buttons](https://develop1.net/public/post/2019/12/21/smart-buttons-for-the-unified-interface) which may simplify this process
- You could also look into the [new command bar editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGNKbfZxCj0), and use Power FX to achieve the same results